# Problemas con GET Y module export

Tags: javascript, nodejs, axios, get, module.exports

hola buenas me encuentro haciendo un get con axios

```
axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/${id}/profile?hapikey=${ hapikey }`,
            responseType: 'json',
            
        }).then(respuesta => {
            console.log("contactos encontrados")
            console.log(respuesta.data);
            res.status(200).send(respuesta.data)

        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.log("Error al encontrar los contactos")
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }) 
        
    }
```

me han entregado 50.000 id, los cuales deben ir en el apartado ${ id }. Por lo tanto hice un module export de la siguiente manera

```
module.exports = {
    id: [ '1', '2', '3'....]
   }
```

llame a la variable desde mi app.js

```
var id = require('../../config/id').id;
```

al dar send en postman me lanza un error ya que literal me esta escribiendo las 50mil variables en ${ id }.

```
"https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/1,2,3,4....."
```

Hay alguna forma de ir llamando a la api un id a la vez con algún código? tipo loop o algo? soy muy nuevo en esto y me encuentro estancado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcto, sería usando un loop, y dentro de ese loop, realizar el get, pero no con el id, sino con el contador del loop:

```
for (let index = 0, index < id.length; index++) {
axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/${index}/profile?hapikey=${ hapikey }`,
            responseType: 'json',
        }).then(respuesta => {
            console.log("contactos encontrados")
            console.log(respuesta.data);
            res.status(200).send(respuesta.data)

        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.log("Error al encontrar los contactos")
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }) 
        
    }
}
```

Ahora, el detalle con esto es que hara la peticion una vez por cada id, por lo que si lo que quieres es ir agregando cada usuario encontrado, podrías crear un array, y cada usuario ir agregandolo a ese array:

```
const usersFounded = []
for (let index = 0, index < id.length; index++) {
axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/vid/${index}/profile?hapikey=${ hapikey }`,
            responseType: 'json',
        }).then(respuesta => {
usersFounded.push(respuesta.data)
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.log("Error al encontrar los contactos")
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).send(error)
        }) 
    }
}
console.log("contactos encontrados")
console.log(usersFounded);
res.status(200).send(usersFounded)
```

Comment: Hasta donde yo se `axios` realiza una llamada asincronica, por lo que deberías esperar a que se resuelvan antes de enviar una respuesta.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, en ese caso solo se me ocurre usar async-await para evitar ese problema.